# Enabling Cross Origin Request in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, cors

I have an API developed using ASP.NET WebForms C# Technology, API is returning the response perfectly however I am getting the response in AJAX due to Cross Origin Request error. Can anyone please guide me on fixing it.

Answer (score 4):

in your web.config add

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```